# is there a management studio in this sql server 2008 download?

Tags: sql-server-2008

trail server of sql server 2008 r2,

downloaded not installed

does it have a managemnt studio like sql server 05 express or not?

from where to get it.

Comment: This is a "question about a specific piece of software", and so should be on SuperUser.

Comment: @Borealid - I start to wonder when people put more effort into where a question should be categorised than into answering it!

Comment: Yes, the full versions (not Express) always contain Management Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the SQL Server Trial edition, however if you just want the management tools then you can download the express edition of the management tools from the following link:

- http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx

It sounds to me like you want the "Management tools" download.

I would have thought that the SQL Server 2008 Trial does come with the management studio tools (the full edition certainly does).